# 'Accepted answer' checkmark shifts when a dialog is displayed

Tags: bug, status-declined, accepted-answer

When I attempt to change my vote on an accepted answer and it is disallowed due to the timer, a box pops up that reads 'Vote too old to be changed, unless this answer is edited'. The checkmark shifts to the left until I click on the box to close it, at which point it pops back to its normal position.

This only occurs with **Chrome 2.0.172.43, on Windows XP**. Firefox and IE on Windows XP work properly.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: And please be generous with the freehand-drawn circles

Comment: I only upvote for drop shadows.

Comment: I only upvote for questions that would actually concern or interest someone.

Comment: I'm not looking for upvotes, but pics are forthcoming.

Comment: @Rich You were interested enough to come in and comment...

Comment: Not quite sure what that has to do with voting, but to each his own.

Comment: Rich is just trying to act all cool and detached, while simultaneously hammering on that "upvote" link. In truth, his greatest sorrow is that he can only vote this bug up *once*.

Comment: Logic fails on some people.

Comment: @Shog9: I cannot stop crying!

Comment: @Shog9: Hey, that reminds me of someone that also cannot stop crying!

Comment: +1 for freehand circle

Comment: +0 for no drop shadows

Comment: +0 for still not being anything of interest or concern.

Comment: Moving 2px over...Interesting!

Comment: WITH THE USAGE OF PROPER WEB STANDARDS THIS SORT OF INJUSTICE WOULD NEVER OCCUR!!!!

Comment: Usage, schmusage - unless you mean the browsers' various implementations, in which case YES SIR I COULD NOT AGREE MORE!

Comment: It's *gotta* be IE's fault, somehow.

Comment: @Andy: Agreed! CSS is perfect, why can't these browsers all get their implementations correct?

Comment: @Rich: I don't know, but it'd probably mean an alternate past that didn't include the `<blink>` tag, and then where would we be?

Comment: I know, I know! It is NOT the CSS, it's the images! (Just kidding this time.)

Answer (score 2):

Reproduced on Chrome 2.0.172.43 and Chromium 4.0.202.0

Can't reproduce on Firefox 3.5.2

Comment: Same here: [Build identifier: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)]

Comment: Reporduced on Safari 4.

Comment: Darnit, Webkit!