# How can I determine the beta status of a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, beta-phase

Is the Game Developers site in open or closed beta?

Answer (score 8):

You can look at a [site proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2825/game-development) and see its status.  Game Development is in Public Beta.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are asking for Game Development on area51.

If that is true, it is now in public beta

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2825/game-development

Comment: tha'ts really discouraging as the site is REALLY slow...i thought it was in clsoed beta

Comment: @Sergio you mean slow as in loading times, or slow as in no reaction to a question?

Comment: @Sergio: "REALLY slow"? There were 6 questions bumped just in the last hour. That's not horrible.

Comment: Your circle.  It is not freehand.

Comment: that´s what I like about paint :)
I got -1 because of that?

Comment: Have an upvote from me to balance it out.  You posted 2 minutes before me anyway.  :)

Comment: is that like a rule? you have to mark stuff by freehanded?

Comment: It's not a "rule" as much as it is a guideline.

Comment: really? where can I read that? (totally off-topic here)

Comment: @sebastian no need to read about it: You are initiated now. Freehand circles are mandatory (no pressure of course, but they really are). Additional improvements are: 1. Freehand circles with drop shadows; 2. tastefully and meaningfully placed unicorns. The latter is left to the experts though, it takes a *lot* of skill to do well. This comment will destroy itself in 2 hours. We never spoke.

Comment: Good example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19769/accepted-answer-checkmark-shifts-when-a-dialog-is-displayed

Comment: 3D freehand circles with drop shadows: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/random-sorting-appears-to-screw-with-answer-permalinks The End.

Comment: @sebastian: Sorry, if I'd just glanced at your rep I would have noticed you were new here.  Check out [The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta).  Things tend to get a little strange here.  :)